# Hot features of Ubuntu

Tags: server

What are the hot features we find in Ubuntu?

Comment: Although Ubuntu does have a lot of amazing features, I think your question is a little too open-ended and subjective.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an open ended question, so I will link you to the page Canonical has about this.

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop
http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook
http://www.ubuntu.com/server